# list and data frame show incomplete dataset?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I am trying to create a data frame and have created list first before transferring into data frame. I did not use vector as I have the impression that I need to list out the individual levels stored in a variable? Using Titanic data.  This is the scripts that I used. The result show 6 rows of data when i run head(df2)? I manage to view full data set when I run head(m2).
Which part of the scripts that I need to change?

[image]

```
m2 <- list(Name = lum$Name,Age = lum$Age,Sex = lum$Sex )

head(m2)

df2 <- data.frame(m2$Name,m2$Age,m2$Sex,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

head(df2)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: @user149635 have you tried the solution provided below? If it works, can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Showing only 6 rows is the standard behavior of `head()`.

If you want to see a specific number of rows, you can pass a number as a parameter `head(df, 15)`, for example.

If you want to see the full dataset in your console, use `print(df)`.

Best,

Colin